# What is the difference between a mat object as a byte array and the jpg format?

Tags: java, opencv, byte

I save the `Mat` object as `byte` array:

```
public static void save(Mat mat, String name)
{
    File file = new File(path, name);
    int length = (int) (mat.total() * mat.elemSize());
    byte buffer[] = new byte[length];
    mat.get(0, 0, buffer);
    try
    {
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, buffer);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and I save via `Imgcodecs.imwrite();` but the file size is very different: the JPG file size is less than 100kb but the byte file size is more than one megabyte.

Why is the second file so much bigger?

Comment: you must to know that if you save a Mat object as jpg you will lose data. you can save it as png (  compress the data lossless)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to make it clearer for the users who will help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The first file is an actual compressed image file. The second file is simply a byte array, which is not compressed and therefore contains more data and is bigger.

Check the links below, they explain in further depth what image compression means and the difference between lossy compression and lossless compression.

- http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-image-compression
- http://www.debugmode.com/imagecmp/